# jQuery on scroll toggle between two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

By default I have a navigation bar which has a red background color.

What I want to do is when the users scrolls down more than 100px to change the background to blue and if he goes back to 0px to change the background to it's default state.

I want to do this by toggling between two classes, for example  `<div class="navigation red">` should be the default class and if the user scroll down to add  `<div class="navigation blue">` and if he scrolls back to have  `<div class="navigation red">` again.

Here is my attempt :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
        $('.navigation').toggleClass( "blue");
    }
 });
});
```

But this is not working. Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bifabixelaci/2/).

Any ideas how to get it to work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `toggleClass()` may be the wrong solution for this.  Use `addClass`/`removeClass` instead:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
    $('.navigation').addClass( "blue");
}
else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass("blue");
}
```

Comment: This of course works because .blue is declared later in the css, however if it was reversed then it wouldn't. I would recommend explicitly removing classes you don't want and adding those you do to prevent that type of issue

Comment: It should be enough to infer from.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.navigation').toggleClass("blue", ($(window).scrollTop() > 100));
     });
});
```

Here's the example in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mozuponuneme/1/edit)

Comment: This should be voted as the correct answer. But I would like to give a hint here, that with this solution, there should be a default class added to the html and the alternative class will toggle

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addClass()` and `removeClass()`like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/qhfmw8hx/

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowYmax = 100;
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrolledY > windowYmax) {

    $('.navigation').addClass("blue");
  } else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass("blue");
    $('.navigation').addClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  height: 800px;
}
.navigation.red {
  background: red;
}
.navigation.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation red">scroll me down and up please to see me changing colors...</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call toggleClass everytime the user scrolls. This code would fix this issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && !$( ".navigation" ).hasClass( "blue" ) || $(window).scrollTop() === 0 && $( ".navigation" ).hasClass( "blue" ){
            $('.navigation').toggleClass( "blue");
        }

    });
});
```

The [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fiwuxuxunepo/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're working with adding a class and removing another, i would suggest just using addClass and removeClass for this case. Also you can chain the methods.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
      $('.navigation').addClass('blue').removeClass('red');
    } else {
      $('.navigation').addClass('red').removeClass('blue');
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muxogeyazobo/3/edit)