# Add/remove class with jQuery based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I'd like to remove the class from `header` after the user scrolls down a little and add another class to it. Trying to figure out the simplest way of doing this but I can't make it work here is the code

```
$(function() {
    var $sectionBox = $(".J_section-box"),
    $navbarBox = $(".J_nav-bar-con"),
    navHeight = $(".J_nav-bar-con").height();
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() >= $sectionBox.offset().top - navHeight ? $navbarBox.addClass("J_fixNavbar") : $navbarBox.removeClass("J_fixNavbar")
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery on scroll toggle between two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203466/jquery-on-scroll-toggle-between-two-classes)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I would suggest to use `toggleClass`, what makes it a bit easier and better to maintain.

```js
$(function() {
    var $navbarBox = $(".J_nav-bar-con");
    var navHeight = $(".J_nav-bar-con").height();

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        $navbarBox.toggleClass("J_fixNavbar", $(this).scrollTop() >= $(".J_section-box").offset().top - navHeight);
    });
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10000px;
}

.J_nav-bar-con {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.J_section-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.J_fixNavbar {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="J_nav-bar-con"></div>
<div class="J_section-box"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```